# Processing Rotating lines

Tags: processing

I am trying to make the following using processing but the spacing between two lines are uneven

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QBkH.png)

I used the following code

```
void setup(){
size(300,300);
rectMode(CENTER);
background(0);
translate(150,150);
for(int i=0;i<360;i+=15){
    rect(0,100,5,50);

    rotate(i);
    }
}
```

but i am getting the following result

[sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfhTN.png)

Comment: The effects of rotations are cumulative. You could look into `pushMatrix` and `popMatrix` -- or you could just repeatedly rotate by 15 degrees (also -- you don't want to confuse degrees and radians, which you seem to be doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So what is happening here is:
You are using rotate(i), where i is in degrees.  rotate() takes radians.
To fix this, use `rotate(radians(i))` which converts i to radians from degrees, then rotates.
And also: rotations are cumulative. It rotates by 0 the first time through.  Then by 15 degrees second time.  Then it adds 30 degrees for the third time, now at 45.
So it looks like this:

```
i=0: 0
i=1: 0
i=2: 15
i=3: 45
i=4: 90
i=5: 150
i=6: 225
i=7: 315
i=8: 420
i=9: 540
i=10: 675
i=11: 825
i=12: 990
```

As you can see, the spacing increases every iteration through the loop. To fix this, you have multiple options for the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<360;i+=15){
    rotate(radians(i));//do rotation to apply to the rectangle, converting i to radians
    rect(0,100,5,50);//draw rectangle
    rotate(radians(-i));//undo rotation for next iteration, converting i to radians
}
```

Or:

```
for(int i=0;i<360;i+=15){
    pushMatrix();//store current translation and rotation and start rotations/translations from default coordinate system
    translate(150,150);//redo the translation that pushMatrix() put away
    rotate(radians(i));//do the rotation, converting i to radians
    rect(0,100,5,50);//draw the rectangle
    popMatrix();//pop the matrix, now all the translations we just did are forgotten and the translation before pushMatrix() outside of the loop is kept.
    // but the rectangle we drew keeps the translations.
}
```

Comment: `pushMatrix();//reset the current rotation AND TRANSLATION` your comment doesn't really make sense. `pushMatrix` *stores* the current coordinate system -- it doesn't reset anything. There is no need to constantly retranslate if the initial translation is before the first `pushMatrix` (as it is in OP's code). If you use your for loop as a replacement of OP's for loop you will see that it doesn't work as intended since the net result would be that of `translate(300,300)`.

Comment: This is still wrong after the edit. `popMatrix()` doesn't undo any translation unless there was a translation *after* the corresponding `pushMatrix()`. The problem wasn't just that your comment wasn't correct -- there is an actual bug in your code. In OP's code, `translate(150,150)` was *before* that loop hence before the `pushMatrix()`. Thus -- it is a bug in the code to follow `pushMatrix()` by `translate(150,150)` That line should be deleted and all references to translation should be dropped from the comments. You are pushing and popping *rotations*. The previous translation is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers/comments are good, though you can do this...

```
void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  translate(150, 150);
  int count = 12;               //you can change this to any integer
  for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    rect(0,100,5,50);
    rotate(radians(360/count));
  }
}
```